# Git/Bash in Windows changes tabwidth

Tags: git, tabstop

I added and commited a branch locally (in a `Docker` container mounted as volume and locally in Windows). 
The file contained tabs which had a width of 2 spaces. (they had two spaces in neovim and in Visual Studio Code) 
Then I pushed that Branch onto `gitlab`. 
And in `gitlab` the tabs I added to that file had a width of 8 spaces. 
I tried using the `autocrlf` option in `.gitconfig` but it did not seem to have an effect.
I did the `add` and `commit` inside the `Docker` container. 
But the `git push` I had to do in `gitbash` because of authentication issues. 
Since I still see two spaces in my local file and in the `Docker` container it must be the `git push` from `gitbash` that changed the tabwidth.

Comment: I would guess that what the file contains is a literal tab character, and you have your local configuration set to display tabs with a size of 2, while on gitlab it's configured to show then as 8.  However, there are configurations in Git to automate tab/space conversion, maybe you have one of them enabled? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2316677/3216427

Comment: Note that [tag:docker] is irrelevant and tag [tag:tabs] is for browser-style tabs, not `\t` characters. The tag [tag:tabstop] is the only SO tag for this that I can find. Git itself doesn't do tab expansion: that's up to your display devices. GitLab, since it's acting as a display device when it produces HTML, does have to do tab expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

joanis answer was correct and led me to the solution.

I solved the issue by adding the `set expandtab` to my `.vimrc` which converts tabs into the number of spaces you set with `set tabstop` and `set shiftwidth`.
So I can do  in vim and it produces actually two spaces instead of a real tab.
If I don't use `set expandtab` the tab is only 2 spaces wide, but it still is a tab and behaves differently in `gitlab`.